# How to disable or re-assign the hotkeys for VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I’d like to know how to disable or re-assign the hotkeys for VirtualBox.

I'd like to type a replacement key combination for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much you can do outside of modifying the Hostkey to create/edit any of the command shortcuts such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>. <kbd>Hostkey</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or using the "Insert Ctrl+Alt+Delete" options under the Machines menu are the only ways to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to the virtual machine.

For more information, see the Typing Special Characters section of [Keyboard and mouse support in virtual machines](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#id2607925) in the Virtualbox manual.

> Host operating systems reserve certain
> key combinations for themselves. For
> example, it is impossible to enter the
> Ctrl+Alt+Delete combination if you
> want to reboot the guest operating
> system in your virtual machine,
> because this key combination is
> usually hard-wired into the host OS
> (both Windows and Linux intercept
> this), and pressing this key
> combination will therefore reboot your
> host.

It goes on to say:

> If, instead, you want to send these key combinations to the guest operating system in the virtual machine, you will need to use one of the following methods:
>
> Use the items in the "Machine" menu of the virtual machine window. There you will find "Insert Ctrl+Alt+Delete" and "Ctrl+Alt+Backspace"; the latter will only have an effect with Linux or Solaris guests, however.
>
> Press special key combinations with the Host key (normally the right Control key), which VirtualBox will then translate for the virtual machine:
>
> Host key + Del to send Ctrl+Alt+Del (to reboot the guest);

I think the short version is that the only way you can change the hotkey needed for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is via changing the Hostkey and using <kbd>Hostkey</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> (as said in the other response). The only command that is "customizable" is the use of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and that is limited to be able to choose which machine (host or virtual) the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> command affects.

Outside of that, unless there is a Addon for Virtualbox to give this support, I think we will just have to wait for that sort of support to be included in future releases.

Answer (score 2):

In VirtualBox 5.1 you can remap the host key to anything you want, even a combination of keys. You can also map individual specific VirtualBox features to any keyboard combinations you like. You'll find it under `VirtualBox > Preferences > Input > Virtual Machine`

[image: VirtualBox Input Settings]

Personally I don't use the Host keyboard shortcuts at all, I've hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> so many times accidentally, thinking it'll copy but it takes the app out of full screen! So I map the Host key to both <kbd>Cmd</kbd> keys simultaneously which gets it out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's only possible to modify the Host key from File -> Preferences -> Input. If there's a way to modify other shortcuts, I'm interested in that, too.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the command-line option:

Assigning the value 0 turns this off completely. Other numbers correspond to key combinations. For instance, the default right Ctrl key is assigned the number 65508

- Disabling the host key

  ```
  VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/Input/HostKeyCombination 0
  ```
- Checking the value of the host key

  ```
  VBoxManage getextradata global GUI/Input/HostKeyCombination
  ```

There is a [relevant VirtualBox forum topic](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=46523#p210029) which you may find helpful as well.